# Filter collection regarding to some state

Tags: scala

Sorry for blurry description, but I can't describe better. So, the problem - 
I have hierarchy of classes

```
sealed trait GameEvent
case object RoundStarted extends GameEvent
case object MessageSent extends GameEvent
....
```

After parsing game data, I have List[GameEvent]. By business logic, I need provide ability to "view" game at particular round. Start of each round determined by RoundStartedEvent. API method have following signature:

```
def load(id:Int, round:Int) = {
   val game = repo.load(id)
   val view = game.dropToRound(round)
   view
}
case class Game(id:Int, events:List[GameEvent]){
   def dropToRound(round:Int) = {
       val newEvents = //events.filter() How? I need find index of "round"-th RoundStarted event and get all elements before it
       this.copy(events = newEvents)
   }
}

val testData = Game(1, List(RoundStarted//round 0, MessageSent, MessageSent, RoundStarted//round 1, MessageSent, RoundStarted//round 2))
//To retrieve all events before round 2 we calling load(1, 1)
assert(load(1, 1) shouldBe (Game(1,List(RoundStarted//round 0, MessageSent, MessageSent)))
```

I know how to do it imperatively, but what is the better way to acomplish it functionally? Preferrably without libs like scalaz, but if it really concise - I'll accept it as well:)

Comment: Any reason you're using an object and not encoding the relevant round id in the `RoundStarted` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually use a filter since you want to collect events only until a specific condition occurs.

This function will collect the events:

```
  def collectEvents(round: Int, events: List[GameEvent]): List[GameEvent] = {
    def collectEventsList(r: Int, eventList: List[GameEvent], collectedEvents: List[GameEvent]): List[GameEvent] = {
      eventList match {
        case RoundStarted :: _ if r == 0 =>
          collectedEvents
        case RoundStarted :: y if r > 0 =>
          collectEventsList(r - 1, y, RoundStarted :: collectedEvents)
        case x :: y =>
          collectEventsList(r, y, x :: collectedEvents)
        case List() =>
          collectedEvents
      }
    }
    collectEventsList(round, events, List()).reverse
  }
```

Comment: I thought about recursion as well. Personally, I don't think it is much more elegant(and clear) than imperative version, so I am in doubt. I'll accept your answer, if someone not provide more elegant solution:)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the worst of both worlds: it uses `takeWhile` together with mutable `var`. And it is pretty much equivalent to imperative solution. But at least it is short:

```
case class Game(id: Int, events: List[GameEvent]) {
  def dropToRound(round: Int): Game = {
    var cnt = 0
    val newEvents = events.takeWhile({
      case RoundStarted => cnt += 1
        cnt <= round
      case _ => true
    })
    this.copy(events = newEvents)
  }
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is a more pure translation of the imperative code:

```
case class Game(id: Int, events: List[GameEvent]) {

  def dropToRound(round: Int): Game = {
    val newEvents = events.foldLeft((List.empty[GameEvent], 0))((t, ev) => (t, ev) match {
      case ((out, cnt), _) if cnt > round => t
      case ((out, cnt), RoundStarted) if cnt == round => t
      case ((out, cnt), RoundStarted) => (ev :: out, cnt + 1)
      case ((out, cnt), _) => (ev :: out, cnt)
    })._1.reverse

    this.copy(events = newEvents)
  }
}
```

The obvious drawbacks are:

1. You can't stop `foldLeft` so it goes through the whole list of events anyway
2. Additional `reverse` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, that almost exacly my initial code) I am just was interested is pure-functional approach can provide someth better. I thought about State monad, but my coworkers is mostly scala newbies and it is absolutely overdesign, so I am really in doubt

Comment: @AndreiMarkhel, I've added another attempt but it is also not without its own drawbacks.